# Study the convergence of $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x} e^{\frac{-1}{x}} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I stumbled upon this integral in a probability exercise

$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x} e^{\frac{-1}{x}} dx$ an I am having trouble trying to prove if it converges or not. I tried to change variables or to bound it, but nothing. I haven't gotten  anything worth putting here. Can someove shed some light?

Answer (score 5):

With the sustitution
$$t=\frac 1x$$

the integral will have the same nature than

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}dt$$

by the limit comparison test near $ 0^+$

we have

$$\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\;\sim \frac 1t \;(t\to 0^+)$$

but

$$\int_0^1\frac{dt}{t}\text{ is divergent}$$

thus, your integral from zero to infinity is divergent.

Comment: I think you meant $+\infty$ in the last integral instead of 1? otherwise how do you get rid of the upper limit?. How can I determine if the the divergence is  due to the lower , upper of both of the limits?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO No, it is one. If the integral from zero to one is divergent then the integral from zero to infinity is Divergent.

Answer (score 3):

Hint : $$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}x\,\frac{1}{x}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}=1.$$

Comment: I really don't know how that can show up, I already lost all day with this

Comment: I think should be more pedagogical if we write $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x}e^{-1/x}}{\frac{1}{x}}=1$. By other hand @J.C.VegaO it means that $\frac{1}{x}e^{-1/x}$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ are asymptotically  equivalent around $+\infty$ and it is a notion of functions "eventually" becoming "essentially equal". So the divergence of integral in your post is follows of divergence of $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x}\, {\rm d}x$ by Limit Comparison Test for Improper Integrals. However,  I think here should be explain what's about the improperties at $0^{+}$.

Answer (score 0):

Focus on $\int_1^\infty\frac 1x e^{-1/x}\,dx$. Using the inequality $e^t\ge 1+t$, we have
$$\frac 1xe^{-1/x}\ge \frac 1x-\frac{1}{x^2}\ge 0 $$
for $x\ge 1$. What can you say about the convergence/divergence of
$$\int_1^\infty\left(\frac 1x-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\,dx\quad$$
(Hint: this integral can be tackled directly.)